# getFragmentManager() return null after screen rotation

Tags: java, android

In one of my fragments I have button that creates FragmentManager object with getFragmentManager() method. It worked fine, but after rotating device's orientation, getFragmentManager() called with that button returns null.

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    if(fm != null){
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, myFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

So in this case, code inside this 'if' never happens after I rotate screen.

EDIT:
my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Did you use `setRetainInstance(true)` on your fragment? I would also try using `getActivity().getFragmentManager()` instead because it is supported in earlier APIs.

Answer (score -3):

Prevent the recreation of your activity after rotation, add this on your Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: After adding this line, my application stops using landscape-designed layouts so that mess up whole application

Comment: Which method of your activity do you use the fragment manager?

Comment: I use it in my fragment, I'm using nested fragments there. MainActivity has 3 fragments reachable via ViewPager, and one of those fragments has that button which swaps its container with another fragment. This button returns null after screen rotation